# What is included in the ‘standalone’ vs ‘cluster’ Milvus deployments?

Tags: database, cluster-computing, milvus

What is included in the ‘standalone’ vs ‘cluster’ Milvus deployments?
Standalone makes it sound like it is a single instance, but as far as I can tell it still requires deploying ETCD and MinIO.

Answer (score 0):

A description of embedded Milvus is given here: [Using Embedded Milvus to Instantly Install and Run Milvus with Python](https://milvus.io/blog/embedded-milvus.md)

A summary of the differences between Embedded, Standalone, Cluster and Cloud is also given.

[image]